# how to calculate a summation in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, sum, numeric

I have an equation to get the summation of  ∑ X + 4 ∑ X *26* Y + ∑ Y 
I just started using matlab and I want to use it to calculate the result

what I have is an array with values of X, array with the values of Y both arrays have the same length

-I found a function but didn't get how to use it 
numeric::sum(f(x), x in {x1, x2, …})
-I can't use the value of i (summation counter) not the values i need

can I calculate the result without using for loops?
or is there a way to calculate the terms in X and in Y each one separately with loops and the ones with both terms in with for a loop

Comment: `numeric::sum(f(x), x in {x1, x2, …})` is not Matlab syntax. If you have a vector `v`, just use `sum(v)`.

Comment: Read the top of the page of the [documentation for `numeric::sum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/numeric-sum.html). It is actually possible to use MuPAD functions from within Matlab, but your question is not clear and you probably don't need this. I recommend learning more Matlab first so that you can ask a question with actual code. Go through some [tutorials](http://www.mathworks.com/academia/student_center/tutorials/launchpad.html).

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when searching for matlab functions online, if you see things with double colons (like `numeric::sum`), they're likely to be MuPAD functions. You can run MuPAD within matlab, but you don't need to. In matlab, just use sum(x) and you'll get an answer.
When you're just starting to learn matlab, a great command is [`lookfor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lookfor.html). In the command line, just type in things like `lookfor sum` and it will return a list of functions that you can explore.